# Why doesn't my code change when I ask for user input and append that to a list?

Tags: python

I wanna store in a list all user inputs collected over time. I did something like this:

```
reactions = []
reaction = raw_input("I wanna know your reaction, yo: ")
reactions.append(reaction)
```

but even after refreshing, my code looks exactly the same, an empty list.

Comment: if you print reactions it will have one input, but when you restart the program reactions is re-initialized to an empty list

Comment: Do you want to run the script multiple times, saving all the reactions?  In that case you'll have to write the reactions to a file so it isn't cleaned up when your program ends

Comment: @depperm ohhh so it doesn't have the power to change my code?

Comment: user input that goes into variables is not 'your code'. your code is what you typed.

Comment: it changes reactions while the program is running, but once it stops it goes away

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes I want it to run multiple times. I'm new at this stuff, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: when you restart the program, you set reactions to an empty list. even if variables were saved between invocations of the interpreter (which they aren't) the result would be the same. reactions is empty and then you add whatever the user typed that one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just save them to a file

```
reaction = raw_input('Please React: ')
with open('reactions.txt', 'a') as f: #a is append mode
    f.write(reaction + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code and print reactions I get whatever I entered. If you want to collect a lot of reactions, you could make a loop, which ends once the user enters "q":

```html
reactions = []
reaction = raw_input("I wanna know your reaction, yo: ")
while reaction != "q":
    reactions.append(reaction)
    reaction = raw_input("I wanna know your reaction, yo: ")
print(reactions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "refreshing". But your code creates a new empty list at the beginning, so if you run it again, it will always append to a new empty list. Try to see your code as a list of instructions that execute one after another in sequence.

maybe add at the end a way to show the contents of the list `print(reactions)` and a loop to repeat the last two lines multiple times:

```
reactions = []
while True:
    reaction = raw_input("I wanna know your reaction, yo: ")
    reactions.append(reaction)
    print reactions
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I ran your code and I wanted something that only asks for a reaction once then ends; and everytime you rerun the program it would print all the reactions from previous players including yours.

Comment: Then you must store the data somewhere else. Lists don't persist between runs, you must use a database, or a file, or something permanent